# Storage folder not creating after successfully running symlink

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I'm trying to link storage folder on my cpanel shared hosting. It used to work ok before, but since now I've upgraded the version to Laravel 9, I'm running my symlink file which is showing blank page as well but not creating a storage folder in my directory. Tried everything from removing storage folder to running through routes.

```
$target ='/home/cpanelusername/tlcapp/storage/app/public';
$link = '/home/cpanelusername/tlc.musafhanif.com/public/storage';
symlink($target, $link);
```

Answer (score 0):

These are some examples

```
 $name = $request->file('NameFiles')->getClientOriginalName();
    $size = $request->file('NameFiles')->getSize();
    $path = $request->file('NameFiles')->storeAs('Path', $name);
    or 
    $path = $request->file('NameFiles')->store('Path', $name);
```

```
    php artisan storage:link
```

```
    chmod -R o+w [nameofyourproject]/storage
```

```
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/filesystem#main-content
```

Comment: Actually, the problem was I was uploading it as ('public/images'). That's why it was creating public folder inside another public folder. Now I replace with ('/images') only and all is working fine